# How to extract ids and classes from a webpage using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

This is my code so far :

```
import urllib2
with urllib2.urlopen("https://quora.com") as response:
    html = response.read()
```

I am new to Python and somehow I am successful in fetching the webpage, now how to extract ids and classes from the webpage?

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do so would be using the BeautifulSoup (bs4) web-scraping library, and requests.

After having installed both using pip, you can start as so:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://quora.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

To find an element with a specific id:

```
soup.find(id="your_id")
```

To find all elements with the "Answer" class:

```
soup.find_all(class_="Answer")
```

You can then use `.get_text()` to remove the html tags and use python string operations to organize your data.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to parse the html code using dedicated libraries, for instance BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Actually my friend assigned me this job. Does extracting classes and ids from a webpage means extracting the class or id names, right?

Answer (score -1):

you can do it easly by xml parsing

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://google.com')
with open('/home/Desktop/test.txt','wb') as f : 
   f.write(page.content)
```